# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Production

Tags: angular, devops, production-environment

**Version Details**

- Angular Version: 7.3.7

I read about this error and found out that this cannot get in the Production but I am getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Production Environment.

**Error Message:**

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value:'ng-valid: true'. Current value: 'ng-valid: false'.`

**Configuration in `Angular.json`:**

```
"qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true
            },
```

**Script for building**

```
node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --configuration=qa
```

**Question:**

> My question is How am I getting this error in production and how can I fix it?

**Updated**

> I just noticed this line `Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.`

**Question:**

So i am running this script for building what else I need to do to enable production?
`node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --configuration=qa`

`Image of error in browser:`

[image: img]

`Image of environment`

[image: img]

Comment: It seems you have reactive form in your code that causes error, please add relevant code.

Comment: What command was used to build? Clearly you are running a dev build here.

Comment: But my question is How it get in the production? It is not supposed to get in there right?

Comment: @theMayer it's in the question

Comment: @theMayer I have added configuration and build command in the question. Can you please look into that and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @JoharZaman Could you please reference where it says this error should not be in production. Just curious.

Comment: Don't think it's relevant, but make sure that your environment.qa.ts also has the production flag to true. Also when you load your app, do you get this message? `Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.`

Comment: @MaihanNijat https://angular.io/guide/deployment#enable-runtime-production-mode This error is caused by these dual change detection cycle checks. *Shouldn't* appear in a prod build

Comment: @Narshe I have updated my questiona and add more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Main.ts` should contain the following contents:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

So, two things need to be true. This needs to exist above in `main.ts`, and your `environment.qa.ts` file must have `production = true`. After verifying this, set a breakpoint here to ensure the values are what you think they are.

**Additional Thought**

You didn't ask, but I'm going to offer it anyway - you need to fix the error. The presence of the `ExpressionChanged...` error indicates a problem with your application logic - most likely, you are manipulating a variable inside one of the [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) (e.g. `AfterContentInit`). This is unlikely to have a noticeable effect, but you *could* encounter some strange bugs as a result of this error.

Comment: thanks for the solution. 
I have already fixed the error in the Development also. :)

Comment: The problem was, I had different environments but i didn't have condition for all of the environments for enableProdMode()